# Importing react libraries into Codepen (namely prop-types)

Tags: reactjs, codepen

There is a nice simple react ES6 example on codepen.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZxXQxp/

I would like to use this as a base for some investigations I want to make in react type checking, namely the 'defaultProps' feature.

'DefaultProperies' is a very simple type checking feature but unfortunately it lives in another library now. At the top of my component I have to import it like this :

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

What steps would I need to make in codepen to import an external react library? It seems like there is no possible way to import the most basic of react libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the `prop-types` library in the Pen. To do so:

1. click the settings button at the top right of the pen:   [image]
2. select the "JavaScript" tab
3. set the preprocessor to "Babel"
4. add `react`, `react-dom`, and `prop-types` to External Resources

   1. react: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.development.js
   2. react-dom: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js
   3. prop-types: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.6.0/prop-types.js

This is what the settings window should look like:

[image]

Then, in your javascript, you may access `PropTypes`:

```
const DumbButton = ({ name, label, onClick }) => (
  <button name={name} onClick={onClick}>{label}</button>
)

DumbButton.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}
```

See this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/sbolel/pen/vYXbKRG?editors=0010#0) for a working example.

Comment: thanks, but how can I explicity import PropTypes from prop-types? What if there is another PropTypes in another js library that I am importing? I need to be able to discriminate like I can with the Node/ES6 'import'

Comment: You cannot import, you have to use the browser version of the script. The reason you cant import is because codepen doesnt build, just runs. Perhaps give https://codesandbox.io/ a try?

Answer (score 0):

2024 Update:

The solution that @sbolel shared still works, but there is now an additional way.

CodePen now supports `import`. Do everything that @sbolel shows, except instead of "External Resources", use "Add Packages", which lets you search for packages by their npm name. Selecting packages will insert lines at the top of your code:

```
import ReactDOM from "https://esm.sh/react-dom";
import React from "https://esm.sh/react";
import PropTypes from "https://esm.sh/prop-types";
```

[image]

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/zvakanaka/pen/XWQrzQY?editors=0010) of working example.